# Qt QProcess startDetached can't end process (bash session)

Tags: c++, bash, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to call a shell script from a Qt GUI, but after running the script, the bash session stays open when it should finish.

Having this code:

```
QString s = "./script.sh " + argument;
qint64 *pid = NULL;
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "-c" << s, NULL, pid);
bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1);
std::cout << "ended";
```

So after running the script, it is expecting a command to be entered, I can put any command and it will execute it. The problem is that it never finishes until I enter a command.

I also tried modifying the `s` variable like this:

```
QString s = "./script.sh " + argument + " ;exit";
```

hoping that it would end up the bash session, but nothing happens.

If instead of using the function `startDetached` I use `start` it does close the bash session without the `;exit` command.

Hope someone knows how to solve it or a workaround!

Comment: What's the script and the argument?  Alternatively, can you reproduce this with a standard command, such as `bash -c "echo done"`?

Comment: A standrad command will reproduce the behaviour I want. The script has 2 commands and then a `exit 0` to end the script. The commands are executed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`startDetached()` is a static method; you started a new process, but it's not represented by the `process` object.

When you wait for `process` to finish, it will wait forever, because `process` was never started.

Try something like:

```
process.start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "-c" << s);
bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

You might want to redirect I/O before `start()`.

Comment: Also, the whole point of `startDetached` is to start and detach the process from current process, so waiting for it makes no sense really.

Comment: Yes, hyde that was not my question. That line is there for testing purposes. My question is how can I do for the child process to end, since it gets stuck in a bash session. Also tried the start() method but I need it non-blocking.

Comment: @deuseux, I don't fully understand what you're trying to do:  `start()` doesn't block; `startDetached()` creates a non-child (therefore non-waitable) process.

Comment: @TobySpeight, so if everything was right after executing `startDetached`, there is no worry to execute it again and again... we don't need to end the process?